# Бот должен оправлять сообщение после любого ответа пользователя в опросе. Как сделать?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def quiz(call):
if call.data == 'quiz':
    question = "2+2?"
    answer = ['1','8','4','2']
    message = bot.send_poll(
        chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
        question=question,
        options=answer,
        type='quiz',
        correct_option_id=2
    )
```

есть такой код, надо что бы после любого ответа бот сразу же оправлял текст("Правильно"/"Неправильно" или тп.) Как это сделать?

Comment: добро пожаловать на сайт !!! MRUT, полезная ссылка, как задать вопрос на данном ресурсе.
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask